# Local emails and external mail server

Tags: linux, email

I have two servers:
alpha - main www server (nginx, php, python, ror)
omega - mail server (dovecot, postfix, spamd, clamav)

I don't want to have possibility to send any emails on alpha however some apps need to send alert emails (rkhunter, CSF/LFD).

How to achieve this? Should I install Postfix and configure it to local delivry only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the applications. Where are you sending the mails to? Your own account? Many applications will let you configure to send notifications to an external mail server.

On the other hand some prefer handling things locally.

You can save yourself some complication by configuring Postfix on the local server and tell Postfix to relay all the mail to your "actual" mail server. Then all your notifications and alerts will think they're working locally while really postfix is relaying it to your actual mail server.

Comment: I've set up an alias `root: acc@domain.tld`. I'm sending those alerts to webmaster@domain.tld - just looking for the simplest method :)

Comment: Simplest would probably be configuring Postfix on the local system and letting it only accept mail from the local system.